# I did not understand the approach needed to solve this problem on inverse proportionality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ratio

The concentration of an acid solution is inversely proportional to the volume the solution if the amount of the acid is not changed. A $40$% hydrochloric acid solution becomes $30$% solution when $30$ L of water is added to it. Find the original volume of the solution.

I understood this much that ratio of the concentration will be $4/3$ hence,ratio of the volume will be $3/4$ since it has been given in the above question that concentration is inversely proportional to the volume. But, I did not understand how to solve the question ahead when 30L is added to $40%$ of the hydrochloric acid.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Volume 2=Volume 1+30L.

Volume 1$\times$Concentration 1=Volume 2$\times$Concentration 2

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ denote the volume of the acid.

Let $w$ denote the volume of the water.

Then we need to solve the following system of $2$ equations in $2$ variables:

- $\frac{a}{a+w}=\frac{40}{100}$
- $\frac{a}{a+w+30}=\frac{30}{100}$

---

$\frac{a}{a+w}=\frac{40}{100}\implies100a=40a+40w\implies60a=40w\implies3a=2w$

$\frac{a}{a+w+30}=\frac{30}{100}\implies100a=30a+30w+900\implies70a=30w+900\implies7a=3w+90$

---

$[3a=2w]\wedge[7a=3w+90]\implies$

$[21a=14w]\wedge[21a=9w+270]\implies$

$[14w=9w+270]\implies$

$[5w=270]\implies$

$[w=54]$

---

$[3a=2w]\wedge[w=54]\implies$

$[3a=108]\implies$

$[a=36]$

---

Hence the original volume of the solution is $54+36=90$.

Answer (score 0):

We can proceed this way. 
$$\begin{array}
&\text{Total volume  } & \text{  Water   } &  \text{  HCl   }\\
x & 0.6x & 0.4 x\\
x+30 & 0.6x +30 & 0.4x\\
\end{array}$$

Thus, we have $$\frac{0.4x}{x+30} = \frac{3}{10} \Rightarrow x =90$$ Hope it helps.

Comment: How you got $3/10$

Comment: @Coder Singh The solution later becomes $30$% of original so $30$%=30/100=3/10.

Answer (score 0):

Let Initial concentration = a

Final concentration = b

Initial volume = x

Final volume = y

Concentration of an acid solution is inversely proportional to the volume.

a inversely proportional to x.

a = k.$\frac{1}{x}$   (some constant)

a.x = k

Also,

b.y = k

So from both equations we have

a.x = b.y

40% . x = 30% . y

y = $\frac{4}{3}$x

Also,

y - x = 30

$\frac{4}{3}$x - x = 30

x = 90

So intial volume is 90.